# Where are applications installed via Applications Manager stored

Tags: intellij

I am new in Ubuntu. I have installed Intellij Idea via inline Applications Manager. But I can't find path of Idea and I can't find in google where Idea path is. Can you tell me please how can I find Idea's path in Ubuntu?

P.S. Currently I need to delete directory `jre64` from Idea's path because I want to make it run under JDK 11.

Comment: I have directory `.IdeaIC2019.1` in my home directory, but I can't find here `jre64` folder, I suppose this is just a little part of application.

Comment: Are you trying to specify a SDK for a new or existing project?

Answer (score 0):

Applications in Linux are actually stored in a range of locations. An executable, the file you run to start the program, is stored in a folder in your path, typically in `/user/bin' for graphical applications that come with software center. The main program files may then reside under /usr/lib. Some configuration data may have been written under /etc/, etc.

*In summary, it is quite complex to answer where applications installed via package manager are stored.*

To **find out what files have been installed** by an application installed through software center, you can use *Synaptic package manager*. Synaptic is not installed by default. Install it using software center or with the command `sudo apt install synaptic`.

- Fire up synaptic (you need to provide your user password because the application runs with root permissions).
- Search the program (package) you installed.
- Right-click the package and select "Properties".

The "*Installed files*" tab lists all individual files that the package installed onto your system. The "*Dependencies*" tab lists all packages that the package you are looking at, depends on.

When you installed your program, any of these dependencies that were not yet on your system, will have been installed as well. Looking up these dependencies in Synaptic will allow you to view the files these dependent packages installed.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is designed as a multi-user operating system. That means that applications are NOT installed within a single User's /home dir by system applications like apt or snap. It also means that some executables, libraries, services, lockfiles, and others are all stored in standard locations.

This is, of course, very different from the way Windows (which is designed as a single-user OS).

A `.application` dir (or file) in your /home/Your_User dir contains only your own profile and data, of course. Not the application itself, not system-level settings, etc. Note that uninstalling the application WON'T remove this data - you must trash it yourself.

If you installed a deb package using apt, use the command `dpkg -L <package_name>` to see exactly what got installed where.

If you installed a snap package using snapd, then the application is in /opt.

The Software Center installed both debs and snaps - only you can determine which you installed.